# Adding class active to a known tab

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

Is it possible to add a class active to a known tab in different page.

When i navigate to page 2 from page 1 i have to make tab 2 as active. I have the tab Id with me.

Can any one tell me what should I do?

My code

```
<div ng-repeat="t in data" class="time-tab-adspace" ng-class="{'tab-align-center':data.length==2}">
    <a class="nav-people-tab text-hover" data-toggle="tab" ng-class="{'nav-people-tab-hover in':seltab=='ticket'+t.id}" ng-click="selecttab(t)"></a>
</div>
```

In the above code i get what is my selected tab and css like `nav-people-tab-hover in` gets applied when i click on it. Now when i click on continue below controller button gets executed.

```
$scope.seltab= tselected;  // here I get the selected tab in page 2
$('#?????').addClass("active").show();
window.location.replace("page1");
```

In the above code What should I write in ????? or some piece of code inorder for me to work this?

Comment: I dont know if I understand your problem, but what about ($scope.seltab).addClass("active").show(); ?

Comment: will try that and let you know

Comment: it didn't work. for me

Comment: Hi..., Both pages using same controller? Don't you use $state and $stateparam?

Comment: yes both use same controller. Can you tell me how to use $state and $stateparam in this case

Comment: I am not using router or route params to naviagate from one to another.... I am only using window.location.replace("/page2")